# MS Access 2010 - How to set up a custom Row-Source for Form ComboBox using criteria from another form element?

Tags: forms, ms-access-2010

I have three tables in particular that I'm working with:

- tblRooms [*ID*, *Number*, *Name*]
- tblKeyed_Rooms [*ID,* *Room_ID*, *Key_Number*]
- tblKeys [*Key_Number*]

I am trying to create a form with two, among other, combo-box elements:

- *Key* from tblCheckouts[*Key_Number*]
- *Room* from tblKeyed_Rooms[*Room_ID*]

where *Room*'s Row Source is any row in tblKeyed_Rooms where *Key Number* = *Key*.

I've tried several different queries based off what I've found searching the internet, most of which were similar to:

```
SELECT tblRooms.ID, tblRooms.Name FROM tblRooms INNER JOIN tblKeyed_Rooms ON tblRooms.ID = tblKeyed_Rooms.[Room_ID] WHERE [Forms]![frmKeyList]![Key]=[tblKeyed_Rooms].[Key Number]);
```

So that in the form, it shows up with *Key* and *Name*.

What can I do to accomplish this using Access 2010? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to join tblKeys to tblKeyed_Rooms, to tblRooms, then limit to the room you are working with on the form. I.E.

```
SELECT 
   K.Number A KeyNumber,
   R.Name + ' - ' + R.Number A Room
FROM
   tblKeys Keys
INNER JOIN
    tblKeyed_Rooms KR ON KR.Key_Number = Keys.Key_Number
INNER JOIN
     tblRooms R ON R.ID = KR.Room_ID
WHERE
    Keys.Key_Number = Forms![frmKeyList]![KeyNumber]
ORDER BY
   Keys.Key_Number
```

Your WHERE condition is a little hard to understand, but basically it can be any Field from the KEYS, KR, or R aliased tables that joins to an available field on the form frmKeyList.

I am unclear on how the Checkouts table fits in. The Keys that can potentially be in that RowSource should be limited to the keys defined in this query for the room on the form.

Comment: tblCheckouts was part of a series of extraneous information I missed deleting initially. What does K.Number A KeyNumber mean? Do you have a link to some documentation on that I could read?

Comment: In your JOIN statement, you can "alias" the joined table, and then refer to it by the alias in the rest of the query. So if I say "INNER JOIN tblKeys K", I can refer to fields in tblKeys as "K.[FieldName]" elsewhere in the quwry. It simply makes it cleaner.